# How to create a new branch on GitHub using the commit's SHA-1 hash value

Tags: git, github

I tried to resolve my problem, but I didn't have any success.

I created a branch on GitHub and made one commit there. After that, I removed a branch, but I know the [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) hash value of my commit. I tried to create a new branch using my SHA-1 hash value, but I couldn't.

I try to do the following:

```
git checkout && git branch - b SPP-69 47127ee98d8247d67f0f2baf3ae316444bc1ea9e
# And got a reference is not a tree 47127ee98d8247d67f0f2baf3ae316444bc1ea9e
```

I try to do the following:

```
git checkout && git branch - b SPP-69 47127ee98d
# And got 47127ee98d is not a commit and a branch SPP-69 could not be created from it.
```

[image]

[image]

I don't have any local reflog.

Comment: Do you have that commit locally?

Answer (score 0):

> I could create a branch but I coud not do it with my commit that has no branch

That means it is no longer referenced by any branch or tag, and therefore is not fetched by default, even by a `git fetch --all`.

Try and click on New Pull request: that should create a [PR branch that you can then fetch locally](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/).

```
git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME
git checkout BRANCHNAME
```

Replace `BRANCHNAME` by the name of the branch you wanted to create.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you don’t have this commit locally on your machine.

```
# Grab the content from the server
git fetch --all --prune

# Now checkout the desired commit
git checkout -b <branch name> <SHA-1>
```

---

#### How can we find out the commit which contains a certain tee object?

You need to find the commit itself and then check it out.

Check your log for that commit and then `checkout -b <SHA-1>` as you did.

Use this script if you can't find it via the Github web interface:

```
#! /bin/sh

# The tee SHA-1 hash value which you are searching for its parent
treeish=<your tree SHA-1 hash value>

# The name of the branch to search in
branch=<branch names>

# Loop over all the commits in the given branch
git rev-list $branch |

    # Search the commits
    while read commit_id; do
        if git ls-tree -d -r --full-tree $sha_id | grep $branch;
           then echo " -- found at $commit_id"
        fi
    done
```

Comment: I think `47127ee` is the commit SHA as shown in the last image (and its parent being `fae7c8c`).

Comment: Its not teh commit its a tree.

Comment: Thank you but after I did   git checkout && git branch - b SPP-69 47127ee  I got the same error fatal 47127ee is not a commit and a branch SPP-69 cannot  be created from it

Comment: @CodeWizard Maybe illustrate my stand with [an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/et0Ov.png)?

Comment: Updated the answer according to your image

Comment: I found this commit I see it on github but I cannot create a branch from it. This commit doesn't belong to any branch (I removed  a branch before it)

Comment: Ha, thats a different story. Do you have this commit locally?

Comment: On which branch is it on github?

Comment: No I have not it locally. It is on a private branch.

Comment: If its in GitHub you can grab it. the first 2 lines of my answer

Comment: I tried to do the same with a commit which have a branch and everything was ok. I could create a branch but I coud not do it with my commit that has no branch